# Getting an array from an API response

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, response

I'm trying to make a simple dad jokes generator on Vuejs with this API https://rapidapi.com/KegenGuyll/api/dad-jokes/details
The issue is that I'm getting an array of the same joke repeated instead of just one. See screenshot: https://prnt.sc/sd5kgk
Plus I'm trying to make a button so that it triggers the fetch function, but I got lost with that axios library.

```js
<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: "Jokes",
  data() {
    return {
      jokes: []
    };
  },
  methods: {},
  created() {
    axios
      .get(
        "https://us-central1-dadsofunny.cloudfunctions.net/DadJokes/random/jokes",
        {
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json"
          },
          params: {
            limit: 1
          }
        }
      )
      .then(response => {
        this.jokes = response.data;
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        alert(err);
      });
  }
};
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<template>
  <div id="jokes-card">
    <div v-for="joke in jokes" :key="joke.id">
      <p>{{jokes.setup}}</p>
      <p>{{jokes.punchline}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Everything looks good in this code. What you see when you do `console.log(response.data);` ?

Answer (score 0):

So, multiple things going on here.

1. Requesting `random/jokes` gives only one joke as an object. requesting [`random/jokes/:count`](https://rapidapi.com/KegenGuyll/api/dad-jokes/details) is used for multiple jokes in an array.
2. You're replacing the state of `this.jokes` with the data object returned from the API, therefore *v-for is repeating the markup for each key on the object*. This causes it to generate the same HTML 4 times, because there are 4 keys.

In order to fix it, you either have to get multiple jokes at the same time by calling the right endpoint, or you should modify your axios call so that the object received from the API is pushed into the array, like so:

```
axios
      .get(
        "https://us-central1-dadsofunny.cloudfunctions.net/DadJokes/random/jokes",
        {
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json"
          },
          params: {
            limit: 1
          }
        }
      )
.then(response => {
        this.jokes.push(response.data);
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation](https://rapidapi.com/KegenGuyll/api/dad-jokes/details),

*/random/jokes* returns one joke

*/random/jokes/:count* returns :count jokes

Therefore, you could change your code to something like below:

```
methods: {
    getNJokes(n) {
        axios.get(`https://us-central1-dadsofunny.cloudfunctions.net/DadJokes/random/jokes/${n || 1}`, { headers: { Accept: "application/json" } })
             .then(response => {
                 this.jokes = response.data;
             })
             .catch(err => {
                 alert(err);
             });
    }
},
created() {
    this.getNJokes(3);
}
```

Then in your template, it should be `joke.setup` and `joke.punchline` instead of `jokes.setup` and `jokes.punchline`.

```
<p>{{joke.setup}}</p>
<p>{{joke.punchline}}</p>
```

Then if you want a button to get an additional joke:

```
<button type="button" @click="getNJokes(1)">Get Different Joke</button>
```

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => {
    return {
      jokes: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getNJokes(n) {
      axios.get(`https://us-central1-dadsofunny.cloudfunctions.net/DadJokes/random/jokes/${n || 1}`, {
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json"
          }
        })
        .then(response => {
            this.jokes = response.data;
        })
        .catch(err => {
          alert(err);
        });
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.getNJokes(1);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="joke in jokes">
    <p><strong>{{joke.setup}}</strong> {{joke.punchline}}</p>
  </div>
  
  <button @click="getNJokes(1)">Get Another Joke</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried your code and it works. However, when the button is clicked, I can no longer fetch another joke.

Comment: @AmineBelmahi I've updated my code so that `@click="getNJokes(1)"` passes 1 instead of the mouse event. I've also included a working snippet.

Comment: Appreciate it! Thank you!